# Converting tuple to list

Tags: python, list, tuples

I am trying to convert this tuple into a list, however when I run this code:

```
mytuple=('7578',), ('6052',), ('8976',), ('9946',)
List=[]
for i in mytuple:
    Start,Mid,End = map(str, mytuple.split("'"))
    List.append(Mid)
print(List)
```

I receive this error:

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'split'
```

The output should be:

```
[7578, 6052, 8976, 9946]
```

Comment: *'tuple into a list'* or *'Tuple To String'* ? Question title says a different story.

Comment: What is the intended output?

Comment: Are you trying to make a list of the values inside the tuples inside of mytuple, eg List = [7578, 6052, 8976, ...etc]?

Comment: @AlejandroAlvarado yes I am trying to make a list of values.

Comment: @MainStreet do you want a list of integers or a list of strings?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

this is what you are looking for

```
mytuple = (('7578',), ('6052',), ('8976',), ('9946',))
result = [int(x) for x, in mytuple]
print(result)
```

Answer (score 4):

If I understood correctly, this is want you want:

```
mytuple = ('7578',), ('6052',), ('8976',), ('9946',)
result = [e for e, in mytuple]
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
['7578', '6052', '8976', '9946']
```

Comment: the question says that the output should be a list of integers, not strings

Answer (score 1):

I would use `itertools.chain.from_iterable` (which errs on the side of too much verbosity than too little):

```
from itertools import chain
result = [int(x) for x in chain.from_iterable(mytuple)]
# vs         ... for x, in mytuple]; the comma is easy to miss
```

Somewhere between the two extremes would be

```
result = [int(x) for x in chain(*mytuple)]
```